# Perforce Visual Studio plugin issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 using Perforce as SourceControl.

My colleague has created multiple projects in a solution which I imported by getting the last revision of the solution.

The thing is, VS detects that the file "ProjectName.csproj.vspscc" has a change type "Newly added file". When I want to check in, I have a message box saying "Failed to check in one or more files. Some files remain checked out or not added.".

This did not happen the first time, and i have checked in my changes once successfully before this. But this error occurs this time.

Can someone help here?